# What happens to Dispatch Pointer after crash

Tags: c++, winapi, com

Assume that I have two processes, A and B. Process A instantiates an IDispatch object in process B (Process A loads the proxy stub, marshalling is done through it). During this, process B crashes and the IDispatch object goes down with it. Process A still has a pointer to something, but when it tries to call a function on that IDispatch object, the marshaller returns an error code. What is that error code? E_POINTER? E_FAIL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll normally get RPC_E_SERVERFAULT.  This is unpleasant behavior, the server is usually toast after this.  A fix is available in Vista and up with IGlobalOptions.  Check [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/01/20/10117963.aspx) for details.

Comment: That's fine if the server is toast. I would like to get an idea of what is returned so that I may handle that specific case and unwind my own objects. So, this is constant behaviour?